# Using regex without creating a regex object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code that checks a URL if it contains a certain pattern:

```
var url = "https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regex%20javascript";
var patt = new RegExp('https?:\/\/[^/]+\.google\.[a-z.]+\/((search[?#])|(webhp[?#])|([?#])).*q=');
var check = patt.test(url);
alert(check);
```

The above regex won't work without using `new RegExp()`. How do I use the same regex without creating the regex object. For example, something like this (which doesn't seem to work):

```
var url = "https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regex%20javascript";
var check = ('https?:\/\/[^/]+\.google\.[a-z.]+\/((search[?#])|(webhp[?#])|([?#])).*q=').test(url);
alert(check);
```

Comment: What makes you think you can do it without creating a regex object? And why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a regex literal like so

```
var check = /https?:\/\/[^/]+\.google\.[a-z.]+\/((search[?#])|(webhp[?#])|([?#])).*q=/.test(url)
```

this is however merely syntactic sugar and does not free you of creating actual RegEx objects

Comment: That's a regex object as well.

Comment: I know but maybe that is what the questioner meant - I could not imagine any other meaning :) Of course my guess could be wrong

Comment: Yeah that's why it would be interesting if the OP would answer the question in my comment. :)